# Change decimal digits for data frame column in R

Tags: r

Questions about displaying of certain numbers of digits have been posted, however, just for single values or vectors, so I hope someone can help me with this.

I have a data frame with several columns and want to display all values in one column with two decimal digits (this column only). I have tried `round()` and `format()` and `options(digits)` but none worked on a column `(numerical)`. I wonder if there is a method to do this without going the extra way of converting the column to a vector and gluing all together again.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried (code)?

Comment: Unfortunately not, deleted it all when it didn't work.. :(

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example of how to do this with the `cars` data.frame that comes installed with R.

First I'll add some variability so that we have numbers with decimal places:

```
data=cars+runif(nrow(cars))
```

Then to round just a single column (in this case the `dist` column to 2 decimal places):

```
data[,'dist']=round(data[,'dist'],2)
```

If your data contain whole numbers then you can guarantee that all values will have 2 decimal places by using:

```
cars[,'dist']=format(round(cars[,'dist'],2),nsmall=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for that CephBirk, I can see the logic behind it, unfortunately it didn't work. The problem is that I am actually dividing 4 digit numbers (e.g. 8000) by 100 to get 80.00 (this is a decimal time measure), so somehow R doesn't want to display it. Tried changing the numbers with Excel, but doesn't feed into R, when adding an actual number with two decimal places (e.g. 0.01) to the top of the column, R displays the rest as 80.00 but as soon as I delete the 0.01 R jumps back to 80. Happen to know of a way just to put a dot behind the second digit?